# how to read json Array or Json Object in rest service?

Tags: java, jersey, xmlhttprequest, jersey-2.0

I made a `XmlHttpRequest` to the below mentioned rest service. i'm sending an array of objects through `xhr.send()` method to the rest service.

```
var object =[  
   {  
      "name":"John",
      "age":31,
      "city":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "name":"John",
      "age":31,
      "city":"New York"
   },
   {  
      "name":"John",
      "age":31,
      "city":"New York"
   }
];
      $scope.onSubmit = function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/abcd/xyz/qwer";
        var params = '';
        xhr.open("POST", url , true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {

            }
        };
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(object) );
};
```

When i ping this rest service without the JsonObject its parameters then its reaching the rest service but when keep JsonObject as its arguement in rest service it is giving unsupported media type 415 error.In the rest service , i'm trying to read the json sent through send() method 
                but its resulting in a error.

```
@POST
@Path("/qwer")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response Service(JsonArray object) {
    String name = object[0].name;
    String age = object[0].age;
    return Response.status(200).entity(" read data").build();

}
```

When i ping this rest service without the JsonObject its parameters then its reaching the rest service but when keep JsonObject as its arguement in rest service it is giving unsupported media type 415 error.In the rest service , i'm trying to read the json sent through send() method      How to read JsonArray or JsonObject in a rest service ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to define/configure a Jackson MessageConverter

```
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
     ...     

     @Override
        public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

            converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
        }
}
```